# How do you get console input and output in a Windowed C++ project?

Tags: debugging, console, window

I would like to make a debug system in C++ where I can get input from a console and output.  Output is the most important, but I would also like to get input to be able to change settings during program execution.

Does anyone have any good methods on solving this dilemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(VS.85).aspx

- AllocConsole
- AttachConsole
- GetStdHandle
- WriteFile
- ReadFile